# How to define Columndefs after DataTables initialization

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

Currently I'm using DataTables in each page initializing them individually like this.

```js
 var table = $('#' + '<%= gvReports.ClientID %>').DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Search Table: ",
                    "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search records",
                    "sEmptyTable": "No data available to display"
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [0],
                        type: 'natural-nohtml'
                    }
                ],
                "sScrollY": "55vh",
                "scrollCollapse": false,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 150, 200], [25, 50, 100, 150, 200]]
            });
```

When I tried to create a generic JQuery method to use in multiple places the type attribute in columnDef is not working properly

```js
"columnDefs": [
                 {
                     "targets": [0],
                      type: 'natural-nohtml'
                 }
              ],
```

Im using NatualSort plugin to sort the data as the column '0' contains alphanumeric data.

Is there a way i can set the columnDefs dynamically? or to set the ColumnDef Type for Column(0) after I initialize the table?
Something Like

```js
table.column("0:visible").Type('natural-nohtml');
```

Any help is appreciated? I want to know if I'm thinking in right way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you can manipulate `columnDefs` *after* the dataTable is initialised. However, when you basically just want to set `natural-nohtml` as `type` for the first column for any dataTable, then you could simply extend `$.fn.dataTable.defaults`. Declare this before you initialise any dataTable :

```js
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: [0], type: 'natural-nohtml' }
  ]
} );
```

This will set any dataTables' first column to type `natural-nohtml`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. i will implement this.